# How to Structure a TypeScript Project like in Java with Modules and Dependencies?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependencies

i have a problem with TypeScript and how to separate modules and import them.

In Java with Maven or Gradle, i can have three modules or projects where:

project-dao: Data Access Object classes
project-dto: Data Transfer Object classes
project-services: Services classes

project-dto is transversal to dao and services, so i can include this module like a project dependency easily in both.

In TypeScript i don't know how do make the same. I see examples with imports of compiled code in Javascript with relative paths or using npm publish for later install in another project.

Someone can i help me with some approach for this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Paolo : I hope your question is about creating different modules and importing them to your root module. If that's the case, you can very well create a new module with @NgModule annotation. if you want to load this module with the root module, just import this in you app.module.ts as

```
import {customModule} from './custom.module';
```

If you just want to load it lazily, include this your routing, with loadChildren property. 
But, if a class that's already declared in another module, whether an app module, @NgModule, or third-party module, do not add this to the declaration.

From a DTO's perspective, I guess, you need to create an incline object  as

```
var userObject = {
  email : req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password
}.
```

UserObject can then be passed to the next layer.